# difference between "deploy" and "new"?

Tags: truffle

So I'm using truffle and I notice that I seem to be able to deploy a contract's bytecode by calling   `deployer.deploy(MyContract);`

But I've also seen people run:

```
myContract = await MyContract.new();
```

in a unit test without ever calling deployer.deploy().

Is my understanding correct? Do these bits of code do the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

They're both similar in that they deploy the contract. The difference is that `.deploy()` behaves like a singleton in that you can access the deployed instance with `.deployed()`. You typically use `.new()` in tests to avoid the possibility of any side-effects.

Here's an example:

Example.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Example {
  uint256 public data;

  function set(uint256 _data) public {
    data = _data;
  }
}
```

Example.spec.js

```
const Example = artifacts.require('Example')

contract('Example', (accounts) => {
  let instance

  beforeEach('setup', async () => {
    instance = await Example.new()

    // second test will fail with `deployed()`
    //instance = await Example.deployed()
  })

  describe('test singleton', () => {
    it('should set data', async () => {
      assert.equal(await instance.data.call(), '0')
      const {receipt: {status}} = await instance.set(5)
      assert.equal(status, '0x01')
      assert.equal(await instance.data.call(), '5')
    })

    it('should not read previous data', async () => {
      // this will be `5` instead of `0` if using `deployed()`
      assert.equal(await instance.data.call(), '0')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I've been using `deployed` in `beforeEach` and I had no inconsistency issues whatsoever. Could you elaborate on what are the fundamental differences, other than the singleton aspect? Or is that it?

Comment: @PaulBerg that's the only difference that I know of. So you're saying that using `deployed` in `beforeEach` resets the contract? I just ran a quick test and that was not the case. See my updated answer

Comment: On a double check, no, it doesn't reset it! In my case, there's a mapping which is added a new object in `beforeEach` so I think that's why there are no side-effects.

Comment: @PaulBerg makes sense

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference is that new() simply deploys a new instance of the contract. But when a contract is deployed by deployer.deploy(), the new instance is saved in the migration for later use with [MyContract.deployed()](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the above functions are used to deploy the contract to the network.

```
deployer.deploy(myContract);
```

is used in our migration file.

We can deploy our own version to the network using the .new() function:

```
MetaCoin.new().then(function(instance) {

// do something

console.log(instance.address);

}).catch(function(err) {

// do something

});
```

Comment: When the test suite starts, the contract deployment code in the `/migrations` folder is run automatically correct? This is important for testing side effects of your deployment code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems reduntant because of the beforeEach and before, before already keeps it in memory as a singleton. beforeEach will create a new instance for each test. So confusing. Two ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: For some contracts it is useful to create and use multiple instances with `.new()`, something you can't do with `.deploy()`.